# How I can check a string with Regular expressions about the string has 12 characters and contains 0-9a-f?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string, match

I want to check a string with Regex whether the string has 12 characters and this contain a-f and 0-9.

Here my code:

```
mac = "000475af588c"; //12 Characters
Match match = Regex.Match(mac, @"([A-Fa-f0-9]+)");

if (match.Success)
{
    //todo
}
```

Comment: You need quantifier, `{12}`.  Perhaps anchors too: `^` & `$`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `{12}` around your character class `[]` to make it 12

```
Match match = Regex.Match(mac, @"^([A-Fa-f0-9]{12})$");
```

Alternately you can use case insensitive option as well:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(mac, @"^([a-f0-9]{12})$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Match match = Regex.Match(mac, @"([a-f1-9]{12})"); what is wrong :(

Comment: @Tarasov Can tell me why it didn't work, and how later you have fixed it?